# Move related product to the sidebar on Woocommerce single products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, widget, product

In woocommerce product page, i would like remove the related product on the product bottom page and put it on sidebar.

I can remove it (on the bottom) with:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_related_products', 20 );
```

and add it in sidebar a widget `[related_products]`. But if I do it like this, I remove all related product.

Have you got an idea, how I could do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just change the location of the related products… Here are the steps:

1) add the following code in your active child theme function.php file (only):

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_related_products',20);
```

2) In backend settings "Appearance" > Widgets:

- Add a Text widget to your product sidebar
- Edit and paste inside the text editor the shortcode `[related_products per_page="3" columns="1"]`
- Save.

[image]

Then you will get something like:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think it may help you.

remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_related_products', 20);

First of all, you will remove the "woocommerce_after_single_product_summary" and overwrite like below.

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'your_function', 25);
function your_function(){
    ...
    ...
}

**Note: If you alter/modify the above hook it will affect in product single page.**

After call related products in widgets via shortcode